# ValidationContext MemberName equals DisplayName

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I created a custom validation attribute that looks something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class MandatoryAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var memberName = validationContext.MemberName;

        DisplayName = AttributeFunctions.GetDisplayName(validationContext);

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return AttributeFunctions.HasValidErrorMessageResource(this) ? base.FormatErrorMessage(DisplayName) : String.Format(Global.MandatoryValidationMessage, DisplayName);
    }
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class Model
{
    [Mandatory]
    [Display(Name = "ResourceName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, the `MemberName` of the `ValidationContext` will always be equal to whatever I put in the `Display` attribute. If I comment the `Display` attribute, then the `MemberName` is equal to `"SomeProperty"` as I would expect.

Is this normal behavior? Shouldn't `MemberName` always be equal to the `PropertyInfo.Name` property?

The reason I say this is because I need to retrieve the `PropertyInfo` from the validation context, and I can't do it if `MemberName` does not give me the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem
it is a bug from webapi, in mvc works fine

class in the webapi source code with bug
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/Validation/Validators/DataAnnotationsModelValidator.cs

working class in mvc 5
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DataAnnotationsModelValidator.cs

i will try to override this, if work i will update this post